# Can't get proper value of variable from suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I am using the shrinkFab function to change the isFabExtended state in Compose. The isFabExtended affects the size of the ExtendableFloatingActionButton.

I want to call shrinkFab anytime the button is clicked. This action should expand the button and shrink it back after 1.5 seconds. Unfortunately this doesn't work because shrinkFabJob is equal to null outside the function for some reason. However, by calling the function three times, on the third time the cancellation of the first or second Job will indeed happen.

At this point, you can press the button many times and it will shrink not 1.5 seconds after the last press, but at any time with visual glitching. What am I doing wrong?

```
var isFabExtended by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
var shrinkFabJob: Job? = null

val shrinkFab: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit = {
    println(shrinkFabJob == null) // null at first and second click
    shrinkFabJob?.cancelAndJoin()
    isFabExtended = true

    if (connectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus.CONNECTED) {
        println(shrinkFabJob == null) // null at first and second click
        shrinkFabJob = launch {
            try {
                delay(1500)
                isFabExtended = false
                println("done")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("cancelled $e")
            }
        }
        println(shrinkFabJob == null) // always not null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that each time the button is pressed, you are calling the shrinkFab function and creating a new coroutine. If you have multiple clicks happening concurrently, the previous coroutines are not being canceled and they continue running alongside the new operations you create. This can lead to asynchrony and interference in the display and execution.

To fix this issue, you can use an updated Job to keep track of the coroutine. In the beginning, define the shrinkFabJob variable like this:

```
val shrinkFabJob = remember { mutableStateOf<Job?>(null) }
```

Then, inside the shrinkFab function, cancel the previous coroutine and wait for it to complete:

```
shrinkFabJob.value?.cancelAndJoin()
```

Next, create a new coroutine and assign it to the shrinkFabJob metric:

```
shrinkFabJob.value = launch {
    // coroutine code
}
```

With these changes, the coroutine activities should be synchronous and executed in order, resolving the issue of visual glitches and overlapping operations.

Additionally, there may be an issue related to connectionStatus and BluetoothConnectionStatus.CONNECTED that is causing errors. Make sure these variables are properly defined and initialized and used.

Finally, utilize the capabilities of the Kotlin language and Compose library to ensure proper synchronization and handling of UI operations to prevent visual glitches.

Comment: thanks, I changed 'var shrinkFabJob: Job? = null' to 'var shrinkFabJob: Job? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }' and that works